# Какие есть способы для вывода древовидного меню в IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Добрый день! Какие способы есть для вывода древовидного меню ? С сервера приходят только корневые элементы, дочерние доставать только запросом по id родителя. Сформировать сразу дерево на сервер не получится, очень большой объем. Может кто посоветовать пример ?

Answer (score 1):

Выводить по одному уровню можно? Тогда подойдет простая таблица. Кликнул по дочернему элементу - загрузил данные, сохранил, обновил таблицу. Кликнул по верхнему элементу - перешел к родителю.

Если нужно загрузить сразу все - грузишь главный элемент, а потом рекурсивно грузишь дочерние. Загрузил все - отобразил вот в таком виде:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32219982/how-to-create-expandable-table-view-like-tree-structure-in-ios

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520533/multi-level-tree-uitableview-in-ios